# Problem 17 from Herstein's book about relation between $C(H)$ and $N(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Denote by $N(H)=\{a\in G: aHa^{-1}=H\}$ and $C(H)=\{x\in G: xh=hx \quad \forall h\in H\}$.

Give an example of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $N(H)\neq C(H)$. Is there any containing relation between $N(H)$ and $C(H)$?

**Proof:** If $x\in C(H)$ then $xh=hx$ for any $h\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $xhx^{-1}=x$ for any $h\in H$. Let's prove that $xHx^{-1}=H$.

If $y\in xHx^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=xh_1x^{-1}=h_1\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $xHx^{-1}\subset H$.

If $y\in H$  $\Rightarrow$ $y=xyx^{-1}\in xHx^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H\subset xHx^{-1}$. Combining these two inclusions we get that $H=xHx^{-1}$.
Thus, $x\in N(H)$ $\Rightarrow$ $C(H)\subset N(H)$.

However we can come up with an example where $C(H)$ is a proper subset of $N(H)$.

Let's take $G=S_3=\{e,\phi,\psi,\psi^2, \phi\cdot \psi, \psi \cdot \phi\}$ with $\psi^3=\phi^2=e$ and $H=\left \langle \psi\right \rangle=\{e,\psi,\psi^2\}$ - cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Then it's easy to check that $C(H)=H$ and $N(H)=\{e,\psi,\psi^2,\phi\}$.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb, Is it normal that I proved these sort of statements via double inclusions? Is it rigorous?

Comment: In your example $N_G(H)$ cannot have order $4$ since it is a subgroup of $G$, having order $6$. In fact, $N_G(H)=G$ here. So the example is still valid.

Comment: Proving inclusion both ways to show $H=xHx^{-1}$ when $x\in C(H)$ and thus concluding $x\in N(H)$ is fine. However your counterexample to $C(H)=N(H)$ is a bit incorrect. Indeed, $S_3$ has no subgroup of order $4$, though you claim $N(H)$ in that case has four elements. For a counterexample, you can pick any normal noncentral subgroup of a group.

Comment: And you might observe that always $C_G(H) \unlhd N_G(H)$. In fact, $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ can be homomorphically embedded in Aut$(H)$.

Comment: I think $N(H)=G=S_3$.