# Give an example of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $N(H)\neq C(H)$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $N(H)\neq C(H)$.?

where its  Denote by $N(H)=\{a\in G: aHa^{-1}=H\}$ and $C(H)=\{x\in G: xh=hx \quad \forall h\in H\}$.

My attempts :  as  as  I  found  this  answer  on  [Problem 17 from Herstein's book about relation between $C(H)$ and $N(H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550886/problem-17-from-hersteins-book-about-relation-between-ch-and-nh)       But  im not  getting  and understand this  answers....and is  there another  groups ?????

$G=S_3=\{e,\phi,\psi,\psi^2, \phi\cdot \psi, \psi \cdot \phi\}$ with $\psi^3=\phi^2=e$ and $H=\left \langle \psi\right \rangle=\{e,\psi,\psi^2\}$ - cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Pliz  help  me

Thanks in advances....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have written the example where $G$ is a nonabelian group of order $6$ and $H$ is its unique cyclic subgroup of order $3$. In this case $C(H)=H$ and $N(H)=G$.

That example generalizes to an infinite collection of examples: take $G$ to be the order $2n$ dihedral group (with $n \ge 3$), and take $H$ to be the order $n$ cyclic subgroup. These can be described geometrically: $G$ is the set of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon (including rotation and reflection symmetries), and $H$ is the subgroup of rotation symmetries. For these groups, $C(H)=H$, because $H$ is abelian and its generator does not commute with a reflection. But $N(H)=G$ (for many reasons, one of which is that $H$ has index 2 in $G$).

Comment: still not  getting in my heads   can  u give me  with  counterexample???